# Why doesn't VS Code's Pylance show function descriptions for opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code, intellisense, pylance

I just installed MS VS Code and installed all of the recommended extensions for Python, including Pylance. In every tutorial for opencv I see, there are descriptions shown for every single function when I type them or hover my mouse above them.

But as you can see in the images below, I get no description.

The information I get:

[image: The information I get]

The information I would like to get:

[image: The information I would like to get]

In the settings.json I already set `languageServer` to Pylance.

I also tried uninstalling all the extensions and reinstalled VSCode.

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not an image.

Comment: The question is not about the code, but about the information displayed by pylance. Thx though

Answer (score 0):

Your picture shows the description of `imread`. As for why it is different from your tutorial, I think this is likely to be related to the ***opencv*** version. You can view your tutorial release time and install the ***opencv*** version of the same period or similar period.

```
pip install packageName==versionNumber
```

*https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/#history*

**About intellisense:**

*https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_autocomplete-and-intellisense
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_intellisense-features
https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/stubs.html*

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is still there. I tried setting up a new installation of VSCode with Python 3.8.5 and the exact same version of opencv like in the video... Still I don't get to see the docstrings. Seems to be a problem with opencv, because it works well with everything else (numpy, pandas, pyautogui etc.) I also tried it in PyCharm, where I get the same issue...

Comment: Can you tell me which version of opencv is?